# How to show images below a select box according to the value?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, ajax

Let's say I have a select box with values : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Every value has it's own image, which I want to display as a description below the select field. Any Drupal / AJAX way to show this?

By the way this is NOT a custom form. This is a node creation and edit form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no ready made solutions for this, and you will need to write a custom module. The way to do this would be to implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify the select element and add a [#ajax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) property.

If you've never written a module with hook_form_alter then this article might be of help: [very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter](http://websmiths.co/blog/very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter)

And here are some relevant questions on Drupal answers:

- [adding-ajax-to-existing-node-form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25637/adding-ajax-to-existing-node-form)
- [how-to-use-ajax-in-form-alter-in-drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27135/how-to-use-ajax-in-form-alter-in-drupal-7)

Comment: This is a good idea, but the select box is also a part of a conditional field. This will override the conditional field applied to the current field.

Comment: After fiddling with hook_form_alter and #ajax property, apparently I had to use : 

1. $form['field_for_ajax']['und']['#ajax'] - to trigger the ajax.
2. $form_state['values']['field_for_ajax']['und'][0]['value'] - to get the value of the select dropdown.

Thanks Alice for the heads up!

Comment: @AkmalFikri Can u post the solution plz?